# kubuntu 16.04: change desktop wallpaper via System Settings application

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde, desktop-background, personalization

I've looked around the System Settings applications and while I can change all sorts of look and feel config, I cannot see a way to change the wallpaper. The only way I found is to get out of the app and do it by right clicking on desktop and then settings.

Or perhaps System Settings wasn't designed to change the wallpaper? Thanks

Comment: have you look in "system settings -appearance ? "

Comment: @JulienChau yes. I've checked Appearance, Desktop and Personalization. Can't find anything.

Comment: is see your problem is solved/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**KDE wallpaper settings**

KDE bugs/wishes: Bug 155056 - Look & Feel -> Desktop does not contain a KCM for the wallpaper - https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=155056

Status at the moment is: WONTFIX

One of the duplicates - https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=371799#c1 :

> Since you can configure the Wallpaper on each screen in each activity
>   separately, it needs to be part of the configuration for that
>   containment.
>
> Systemsettings has no idea what desktop containments you are using,
>   and can only configure global settings.

You could change the wallpaper by:

- Right click the desktop > Configure Desktop > Wallpaper.
- Left click the desktop toolbox > Configure Desktop > Wallpaper.
- Drag&drop an image to the desktop (unlocked widgets).
- Use the 'Set as Wallpaper' service menu (unlocked widgets): https://store.kde.org/p/1169583/ .